# Spring Data Couchbase put @Id attribute to json when embedded

Tags: spring, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I have a one to many relationship namely A and B. A may refer to many B instances. B instances also can be managed independently. 
That's why, B class looks like this:

```
public class B {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String appId;
}
```

A class will refer to a list of B instances. So it looks like this:

```
public class A {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private int age;
    private List<B> bInstances;
}
```

When bInstances are filled with B instances and then A instance is saved, id fields of the B instances are removed from the JSON document since it is annotated with @Id.
I simply need to add this field to JSON when B is embedded into another class.
And when B instance is saved independently, @Id field can be used as the regular key. 
How may I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question specifically, yes the field annotated `@Id` won't get written to the serialized json. Your best bet here is to duplicate the field and set its value in either the constructor or a setter, for example:

```
public class B {
@Id
private String metaId;
private String id;
private String appId; 

public setMetaId(String metaId) {
    this.metaId = metaId;
    this.id = metaId;
 }
}
```

You can `@JsonIgnore` one of them if you don't want to see the duplication in your serializations.

Note: I totally agree with Robin's answer, but there are cases where you want to save the data as-it-was and you want to refer to it in the future.. so you don't care if B instance changed one week after you saved the data. So it really depends on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you to **not** store the instances of B directly in a document of A. Doing this would result in data inconsistencies if an instance of B is changed in another context than A. Additionally you duplicate data unnecessarily if an instance of B is stored in multiple documents of class A.

The desired way to store instances of one class in another is to save the document ids instead. So your class A should look like this:

```
public class A {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private int age;
    private List<String> bInstanceIds;
}
```

Comment: And then what ? Creating the boilerplate yourself to retrieve the sub docs by id ? So there is no relartionnal annotation useable like `@ManyToMany` ? Or `@DBRef` in MongoDb